# FFMPEG -> how to keep the original audio quality during conversion?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, quality

'-ab' option is related to audio quality? how to say ffmpeg to keep the original audio quality during conversion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know that much about FFmpeg but after some Googling I found that you can use `-acodec copy` as parameter to simply take the audio from the source file.

Comment: See the documentation on [stream copying](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) for more information.